# Could any of the "Chosen" have ever turned back to the Light?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, character-development

I know that the Forsaken helped Rand, for their own gain or to harm rivals. But did any ever come back from being Chosen? Could they? Asmodean is the closest thing that comes to mind, but he was still evil, right? Maybe Demandred?
Any evidence one can come back to the "good guys"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Theoretically, yes.

The Forsaken were ultimately selfish beings. They wanted power for themselves, and The Dark One was a way to get that power.

> **INTERVIEW**: Jan 25th, 2005
>   TOR Questions of the Week Part II (Verbatim)
>   **WEEK 1 QUESTION**
>   The Dark One has promised his followers immortality and power above all others on the Day of Return. In previous interviews you have said that this is within his power. My question is, will he? I mean, he doesn't seem very loyal or trustworthy to me. If (Light forbid) he breaks free, will he remember the "little people" or just destroy all the puny humans when he remakes the world in his own image?
>   **ROBERT JORDAN**
>   *"That's the big question for the Forsaken, isn't it. Can they trust the Dark One? You're right; he isn't very trustworthy or loyal. **Greed** leads people to believe strange things, to excuse the most abhorrent behavior on their parts—just check out the nightly news for confirmation—and at the root, **that is what motivates the Forsaken** and, in truth, most Darkfriends. Greed for power, greed for immortality. That makes them believe, because they want to believe. So will he grant these things? Maybe. After all, he gains more willing followers, more eager followers, if he is seen to give rewards. But will he care whether he has any followers at all in a world where he is all-powerful? Flip a coin and check which way the wind is blowing. Maybe you can find the answer there."*

The Dark One was even known to kill off his Dreadlords or Chosen (in the Age of Legends) if He thought they would betray Him.

> **INTERVIEW**: Jan 25th, 2005
>   TOR Questions of the Week Part II (Verbatim)
>   **WEEK 12 QUESTION**
>   In Winters Heart, you mention that back in the Age of Legends, there were several other Forsaken that the Dark One had killed because he suspected they would betray him. What's their story? Were those people ever as high ranking as the 13 survivors, or where they more like high-ranking Dreadlords then actual Forsaken?
>   *... "Some of those Forsaken the Dark One killed were every bit as high-ranking as the thirteen who were remembered, and who you might say constituted a large part of the Dark One's General Staff at the time of the sealing.*"

So, we know that the Forsaken had the potential to seek their own interests, rather than the interests of the Dark One. They didn't necessarily side with the Dark One for any reason other than personal gain.

Thus, there's the groundwork for the Forsaken to betray the Dark One and instead turn to the Light. I think we see a little bit of that with Asmodean, who was probably more helpful to Rand than was necessary for his survival.

If turning to the Light seemed like a better option for any of them, then I think they could have. While the Dark One may have claim to their souls, the Creator is more powerful, and Rand represents a Christ or Savior type. That implies that repentance is possible, even if it may mean the immediate death of the repentant individual.

We also see that *everything* can be undone in the Wheel of Time world. The Taint on *Saidin* is cleansed. Severed channelers have their power restored. The damage from Balefire can be healed. Rand overcomes his darkness atop Dragonmount. So, thematically, there's a lot of support for being able to return to the Light.

RJ even mentioned that if a Forsaken dies, they can still be reborn in the Pattern, as is normal, and their new body/mind isn't affected by their previous incarnation:

> **INTERVIEW**: Apr, 2003
>   Budapest Q&A (Verbatim)
>   **QUESTION**
>   I have an exciting question, maybe, we heard of making the Forsaken reborn, so has the original body any reflection to the mind of the Forsaken?
>   **ROBERT JORDAN**
>   *"Well, if a Forsaken dies and is reborn naturally, through the turning of the Wheel, no."*

I've found no quotes that would speak to the contrary, and I scanned through every quote containing "Forsaken" or "Chosen" from the Wheel of Time interview database (linked at the bottom).

### Practically, no.

As mentioned before, the Forsaken are ultimately selfish beings, and the 13 left during series were the worst of the worst. So, while the option for them to turn sides may have theoretically existed for them, it would never have been something they truly considered or tried out, because of their awful ideologies and personalities.

For instance, they were promised eternal life so long as they followed the Dark One and made it to the Day of Return. We see that He is able to keep this promise, in a way, when several Forsaken are brought back in new bodies. To such selfish people, the chance at immortality would be too great to give up. With the Creator, they would get *reborn*, but they wouldn't be themselves anymore.

Supporting quotes:

> **ROBERT JORDAN**
>   No, they do not believe they are immortal, but they believe they will be. All they need to do is get the Dark One free. And they have been promised this. This is their reward for getting him free. If they manage to get him out of that prison, he will grant them immortality. And they believe this because they have seen him in the past, as he has done now, bring the dead back to life. Give the dead new bodies. Transfer souls from a dying body into a young and healthy body. They've seen him do this. So they know that can be done. So it's not as though they are believing something, somebody just walked up to you and said "I can make you immortal if you go out and do this, kill and do awful deeds". They've seen him, they have seen these incredible things done. So they have reason to believe.

And another quote from Jordan on the nature of the Forsaken:

> Now about how evil the Forsaken are. I'm not really sure you define evil. Part of what I am writing about is just how ordinary evil is. In many ways, without the One Power, the Forsaken would be no more than Darkfriends, though perhaps a bit more than ordinary. True, their callousness toward the pain, suffering, even death of ordinary people, and the way they submerge everything and everyone in their own quest for power—and true immortality—their willingness to deliver the world to the Dark One in that quest, are shared by many who do not have their powers. The point is that they are human; they haven't gotten rid of human emotions, or human weaknesses except for a few physical ones. They are not gods, nor even demi-gods, though they seek to be and think they already are. But believe me, there is nothing they will not do to achieve their goals, no price too high to pay—especially if it is paid by someone else, or millions of someone elses. And Lanfear holding back and doing good for Rand's sake? Ha! She was psychically fixed on possessing a man who never loved her. Even with that, her desire for Rand was as much a desire for power as for him. To be the one to deliver the Dragon Reborn to the service of the Shadow; that would set her above the other Forsaken. And learning that the access ter'angreal for the two huge sa'angreal were still in existence....Sure, she wanted his love—not least because it had been denied her; Lanfear was a woman who claimed a right to anything she wanted—wanted his devotion, but even more than his body, Lanfear wanted power, the power possibly to replace the Dark One, even to replace the Creator. For Rand's sake? Not a chance.

Quotes found on [Theoryland](http://www.theoryland.com/wheel-of-time-interview-search.php).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely impossible for this to ever occur: to become one of the Chosen was to hand over one's eternal soul and service to the Dark One. We've seen that even death isn't an escape from being Chosen, as the Dark Lord had means of bringing back his servants. None of the Chosen ever truly turned during the books, and with all but three of them dead (for good) at the end of the novels, there's very little chance that the remaining will ever even get the opportunity.

Comment: I feel like, given how close Rand was to going over to being evil, there would be more of a chance for redemption.

Comment: Also, I will need to check, but aren't there more than 3 left that are either alive/braindead/not dead by balefire?

Comment: @Seanoseanohay I would never go over to being evil!

Comment: @randal'thor Evil may be relative in this case. You spoiled the lands and caused starvation. You didn't kill the DO and instead let evil (and choice) remain. You killed thousands of sentient beings. You also enter *tel'aran'rhiod* in the flesh, which is an act of evil according to the Wise Ones. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Anyone can turn back to the Light. Its just that almost no one does.  There are only two known cases of turning back to the light in the books, and each lived out the myriad of lives

> (Ingtar and Verin)

There seems to be a neat synergy between selfishness [the quality the DO is supposed to prize most] and betraying the Dark One.

> Ingtar selfishly wanted to reclaim his honor.
>  Verin selfishly wanted to complete and share *the work*

This confluence could lead someone away from the Dark One, even someone like Asmodean, who couldn't go back to being a Forsaken, after what Rand and Lanfear had done to him.